# Why is CakePHP unable to create fixtures for one controller and returns SQLSTATE[42000] while it is for another controller?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, phpunit, fixtures

Quick line out of my CakePHP Application (important part):

I have a users table with all that is needed (Model, Controller, Views, Fixtures, TestCases).
Among other data this user table references to a cities Table, a countries and a streets table.
For the cities, countries and streets everything is there as well and works:(Model, Controller, Views, Fixtures, TestCases).

Fixtrues and Text Cases were built with Bake.

Wihle I can run the TestCases for cities, countries and streets,I cannot run the TestCases for Users as I get this Error Message:

```
Exception: Unable to create constraints for fixture "App\Test\Fixture\UsersFixture" in "App\Test\TestCase\Controller\UsersControllerTest" test case: 
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1142 REFERENCES command denied to user 'cake_user'@'localhost' for table 'cities'
In [/opt/git/premesec/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/TestSuite/Fixture/FixtureManager.php, line 335]
```

What puzzles me is that I can run the fixtures for cities when I run the cities TestCases, but there is a problem when the same fixtures should be run for users TestCases.

Here are the constraints form UsersFixtures.php:

```
'_constraints' => [
            'primary' => ['type' => 'primary', 'columns' => ['id'], 'length' => []],
            'city_id' => ['type' => 'foreign', 'columns' => ['city_id'], 'references' => ['cities', 'id'], 'update' => 'noAction', 'delete' => 'noAction', 'length' => []],
            'fk_country_id' => ['type' => 'foreign', 'columns' => ['country_id'], 'references' => ['countries', 'id'], 'update' => 'noAction', 'delete' => 'noAction', 'length' => []],
            'house_number_id' => ['type' => 'foreign', 'columns' => ['house_number_id'], 'references' => ['house_numbers', 'id'], 'update' => 'noAction', 'delete' => 'noAction', 'length' => []],
            'street_id' => ['type' => 'foreign', 'columns' => ['street_id'], 'references' => ['streets', 'id'], 'update' => 'noAction', 'delete' => 'noAction', 'length' => []],
        ],
```

Here are the constraints form CitiesFixtures.php:

```
'_constraints' => [
            'primary' => ['type' => 'primary', 'columns' => ['id'], 'length' => []],
        ],
```

CakePHP v4.0.6

PHP-Version: 7.2.24

mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.31, for Linux (x86_64)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the error message closely, it's not really about the `cities` table, but specifically about the `REFERENCES` command that your account isn't allowed to run, ie it's the foreign key constraint in your `Users` fixture, which most likely isn't going to be involved in your other tests, ie your other tests aren't loading the `Users` fixture.

Long story short, you either need to grant your `cake_user` account the `REFERENCES` privilege accordingly, which is required for being able to create foreign key constraints, or choose a different user account that already has the required privileges.

See also

- **[MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual > Security > Access Control and Account Management > Privileges Provided by MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html)**
- **[MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual > Security > Access Control and Account Management > Adding Accounts, Assigning Privileges, and Dropping Accounts](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/creating-accounts.html)**